# How to implement a Silverlight modeless child window?

Tags: silverlight

Is there any way to create a modeless child window on a Silverlight application?  Basically I need to display some detailed information after user clicks on a button.  User could keep working on the main page and see the detailed child window at the same time.

Thanks for any reply.

ck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim Heuer has taken the ChildWindow code from the Silverlight Toolkit and refactored it to a modeless implementation. See:

http://silverlightfeeds.com/post/533/Refactoring_Silverlight_ChildWindow_for_a_non-modal_use.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Popup control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for this. Just add your content to the popup and show it.